# NodeJS image processing: how to merge two images with a polygon mask?

Tags: node.js, image-processing, sharp

I am trying to do something the same as this [Merge images by mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72849119/merge-images-by-mask), but in NodeJS Sharp library instead of Python.
I have two images and a polygon, I want the result to be the merged image where all the pixels inside polygon from image1 otherwise image2, more specifically, how to apply the 'mergeImageWithPolygonMask' function below:

```
const sharp = require('sharp')
let image1 = sharp('image1.jpg')
let image2 = sharp('image2.jpg')
let polygon = [[0,0], [0, 100], [100, 100], [100, 0]]
let newImage = mergeImagesWithPolygonMask(image1, image2, polygon) // how to do this?
newImage.toFile('out.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1):

After playing with Sharp library for a while, I come up with a solution, which I think will help other people also as this is a quite common use case.

```
async function mergeImagesWithPolygonMask(image1, image2, polygonMask, config) {
  // merge two images with the polygon mask, where within the polygon we have pixel from image1, outside the polygon with pixels from image2
  const { height, width } = config;
  // console.log("height", height, "width", width);
  const mask = Buffer.from(
    `<svg height="${height}" width="${width}"><path d="M${polygonMask.join(
      "L"
    )}Z" fill-opacity="1"/></svg>`
  );
  const maskImage = await sharp(mask, { density: 72 }).png().toBuffer();
  const frontImage = await image2.toBuffer();
  const upperLayer = await sharp(frontImage)
    .composite([{ input: maskImage, blend: "dest-in", gravity: "northwest" }])
    // Set the output format and write to a file
    .png()
    .toBuffer();
  return image1.composite([{ input: upperLayer, gravity: "northwest" }]);
}
```

This function will first create an svg image and use sharp composite method to create the polygon mask on the front image. And then composite this masked front image to the background image. The size passed in in config specify the size of the svg image.

to use this function:

```
const sharp = require('sharp')
const image1 = sharp('image1')
const image2 = sharp('image2')
polygon = [[682, 457], [743, 437], [748, 471], [689, 477]]
mergeImagesWithPolygonMask(image1, image2, polygon, {height: 720, width:1280})
```